# SQL backup to azure storage failed

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a SQL Server 2014 up and running and I am trying to backup a specific database to Azure storage. I created a credential using the storage account name as identity and the primary key as password. Then I tried to backup the database to URL but I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Backup failed for Server '*****'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "https://******.blob.core.windows.net/backupcontainer/demo_backup_2016_06_22_110957.bak:" Backup to URL received an exception from the remote endpoint. Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
```

Answer (score 10):

I figured out what the problem is. When I created the storage account I choose the kind to be "Blob Storage". It must be "General Purpose" to work. The backup steps was correct, the problem was with the kind of storage account.